# Existence of a minimal set of linear order that is equivalent to the given partial order

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let  $\{(P, \leq_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a set of linear order on set $P$, $(P,R)$ be a partial order on the same set $P$. We say that the former is equivalent to the later, iff: $$\forall a, b \in P[\forall \alpha \in A(a \leq_{\alpha}b) \leftrightarrow a R b]$$

Now given $(P, R)$, can we find a $\subset$-minimal set that is equivalent to it?

**Added**: It's already been known from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271003/every-partial-order-can-be-extended-to-a-linear-ordering) that we can construct a (not necessarily minimal)set that is equivalent to $(P,R)$.

Answer (score 0):

By Dushnik-Miller theorem every partial order is the intersection of linear orders (E.Harzheim, Ordered Sets, Springer, 2005). The minimal number of such linear orders is called a **dimension** of poset.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Cardinal invariance is not the same as $\subseteq$-minimal set.