# show that there's a linear ordering such that $R \subseteq R^*$

Tags: set-theory

Show that if $R$ is a partial ordering on a set $A$, then there exists a linear ordering $R^*$ on $A$ such that $R \subseteq R^*$

Comment: Hint: For the finite case, use induction. For the general case, use the compactness theorem of first order logic. Let $T$ be the theory consisting of the [diagram](http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Diagram) of $(A,R)$ together with the sentence asserting that $R$ is a linear order. Then every finite subset of $T$ has a (finite) model (this is why it's necessary to deal with the finite case first), so by compactness $T$ has a model...

Comment: I am torn between closing this as a duplicate, or does the utter lack of substance doesn't deserve the two minutes effort it will take to find that duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271003/every-partial-order-can-be-extended-to-a-linear-ordering. You answered it :) Note, found it in 1m16s.

Comment: @Brian: I know.

Answer (score 0):

This requires the Axiom of Choice:
The partial orderings on $A$ are inductively ordered, hence by Zorn's lemma there is a maximal partial ordering $R^\star$ among those containing $R$. Then $R^\star$ is linear (as the lack of this property would quickly contradict its maximality).

Comment: Thanks! ...why is it the case that a lack of linearity would contradict maximality?

Comment: @RobertM Um, think about it for a moment.