# Can every poset be toplogically sorted?

Tags: order-theory, axiom-of-choice

A partial ordering $\preceq'$ on $S$ is said to be compatible with another partial ordering $\preceq$ if for all $a,b,\in S$,

$$ a \preceq b \Rightarrow a \preceq' b$$

Given a poset $(S, \preceq)$, a toplogical sorting on $S$ is a total order $\preceq'$ that is compatible with $\preceq$. There is a simple constructive proof that every finite poset can be toplogically sorted. Is the same true for infinite sets? Can every poset be toplogically sorted?

Comment: In other words, can every partial order be extended to a total order. Yes assuming choice. This was covered in multiple threads before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [Szpilrajn extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpilrajn_extension_theorem); it’s a result that follows from the axiom of choice. In fact, it follows from but does not imply the weaker [compactness theorem  for first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) or the equivalent [Boolean prime ideal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem). Its proof from the result for finite partial orders and either the compactness theorem or the equivalent [ultrafilter lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem#The_ultrafilter_lemma) is a straightforward application of either.

Comment: Do you have a reference that discusses this?

Comment: @DavidM: I don’t, I’m afraid, but you could do worse than to start with [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37272/are-all-sets-totally-ordered) in Noah Schweber’s answer, especially the answer there by François G. Dorais, and in connection with that the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271003/every-partial-order-can-be-extended-to-a-linear-ordering) by Asaf Karagila and me.

Answer (score 2):

Choice is indeed necessary - for one thing, even the statement "Every set can be linearly ordered" is not provable in ZF alone! See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37272/are-all-sets-totally-ordered.