# Define non-eventually-constant $f: I \to \{a, b\}$ from arbitrary upwards-directed poset $I$

Tags: order-theory, axiom-of-choice, nets

Is the following provable and how? I feel like I am missing some proof technique or strong theorems, I'd be grateful for any pointer.

> Let $(I, \leq)$ be an upwards-directed poset. Define an $f: I \to \{a,b\}$ such that $f$ is *not* eventually constant.

Upwards-directed ("every path can be recombined"): $\forall i_1, i_2 \in I\ \exists j \in I.\quad j \geq i_1, j \geq i_2$.

Eventually constant ("a path on which $f$ is constant"): $\exists C \in \{a, b\}\ \exists i \in I\ \forall j \geq i.\quad f(j) = C$

If $I = (\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ with the usual ordering, then my solution would be:

> Set $f(0) := a$ and inductively choose $f(n + 1) \neq f(n)$.
> Or put differently, define $f$ recursively by
> $$f(n) = \begin{cases} a &, n = 0 \\ \mathrm{flip}(f(n-1)) &, n > 0. \end{cases}$$

In general, if $I$ is wellordered, then such a (non-constructive) definition by [transfinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_recursion) works.

What if $I$ is not wellordered? While the set $I$ can [always be wellordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), that assigned order is not necessarily compatible with the old order.

---

The question popped up while attempting an exercise in [Dr. Pete L. Clark](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark)'s notes on [nets & filters in topology](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/convergence.pdf), p. 10f., exercise 3.1.11. It asks readers to prove the following statement:

> Within a topology $X$ we have: $$x \text{ is an isolated point} \Leftrightarrow \text{every net converging to } x \text{ is eventually constant}$$

$\Rightarrow$ is clear to me, my attempted solution for the rest:

> For the direction $\Leftarrow$ I'd like to show the contraposition $$x \text{ is not isolated} \Rightarrow \exists \text{ net } f \text{ converging to x, which is not eventually constant.}$$
>
> $x$ is not isolated, hence every neighborhood of $x$ has at least two elements. Define $f: (\mathcal{V}(x), \supseteq) \to X$ mapping neighborhoods to one of their elements, so that $f$ is not eventually constant (**how?**).

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this question under [axiom-of-choice](/questions/tagged/axiom-of-choice), I'd like to add some information about that as well.

> **Theorem.** It is consistent that there is a linearly ordered set without a maximal element, where every net which takes finitely many values is eventually constant.

The proof, of course, relies on a technical construction. Mostowski proved it is consistent to have a linear order which is dense, without end points, and every subset is a finite union of intervals.

Let $(I,\leq)$ be such linear order. Take $f\colon I\to\{0,\dots,n\}$ be any function. Then $A_i=f^{-1}(i)$ is a finite union of intervals for each $i\leq n$. If $f$ is not eventually constant, then there is some $i\leq n$ such that $A_i$ contains infinitely many intervals (every time you switch from $i$ to a different value, and back), so this is impossible.

Therefore every net is eventually constant in this case. $\square$

(This proof extends to define the term as a *Läuchli continuum*.)

So we need some modicum of choice in order to prove the theorem you're talking about. But we do not need to well-order $I$ or anything. We just need to split $I$ into two cofinal sets, which is far weaker, of course. Choice makes it easier, of course: well-order the set, and by transfinite recursion construct the two sets: each step add the element with the least index which is not bounded by some member of your set, and zigzag between the two sets.

Comment: ME Rudin's approach to proofs: well-order everything in sight!

Answer (score 1):

In order for the statement to be true, you need $(I, \le)$ to have no maximal elements; however, you *don't* need it to be upwards-directed—except perhaps to make sense of 'eventually constant'. The only assumption you need is that $(I, \le)$ is a poset with no maximal elements.

What follows is a proof—admittedly not a particularly elegant one—that if $(I, \le)$ is an arbitrary poset with no maximal elements, then there is a function $f : I \to \{ a, b \}$ such that, for all $C \in \{ a, b \}$ and all $i \in I$, there is some $j \ge i$ such that $f(j) \ne C$.

Every partial order $\le$ extends to a total order $\le_{\text{t}}$—that is, if $(I, \le)$ is a partially ordered set, then there is a total order $\le_{\text{t}}$ on $I$ such that if $i \le j$, then $i \le_{\text{t}} j$. The proof of this fact isn't entirely trivial (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271003/) for example) and it depends on the axiom of choice, which is fine by me if it's fine by you. Note furthermore that if $(I, \le)$ has no maximal elements, then neither does $(I, \le_{\text{t}})$.

But then if $(I, \le_{\text{t}})$ is a totally ordered set, you can take some cofinal sequence $(i_{\gamma} \mid \gamma < \alpha)$ in $(I, \le_{\text{t}})$, where $\alpha$ is (necessarily) some limit ordinal, and then define $f : I \to \{ a, b \}$ by letting $f(i) = a$ if $i \ne i_{\gamma}$ for any $\gamma < \alpha$ or if $i=i_{\gamma}$ for some limit ordinal $\gamma < \alpha$, and letting $f(i_{\gamma+1}) = \mathrm{flip}(f(i_{\gamma}))$ for all $\gamma < \alpha$. You can then verify that $f$ is non-eventually-constant on $(I, \le)$.

**Addendum:** A neater and (slightly) more elementary approach under the assumption that $(I, \le)$ is upwards-directed is to simply avoid extending $\le$ to a total order. In this case, the fact that $(I, \le)$ itself has a cofinal sequence follows from the fact that it is upwards-directed.

Comment: Do you have a reference or a short explanation of the notation $(i_\gamma | \gamma < \alpha)$? Having never worked with ordinals before, your definition of $f$ stills seems a bit informal to me. What is the underlying principle? E.g. via transfinite recursion, existence and uniqueness of a solution can be proven.

Comment: @ComFreek: There might be too much to explain if you've never used ordinals before. A cofinal sequence $(i_{\gamma} \mid \gamma < \alpha)$ in $(I, \le_{\text{t}})$ is just a well-ordered (with respect to $\le_{\text{t}}$) subset of $I$, such that for each $i \in I$, there is some element of the subset that is $\ge i$. The existence and uniqueness of the function $f : (I, \le_{\text{t}}) \to \{ a, b \}$ as defined follows from transfinite recursion (in much the same way that the existence of the $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{ a, b \}$ in your question follows from regular recursion on $\mathbb{N}$).