# Extension of a partial order to a total order

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, order-theory, alternative-proof

There're are excellent answers by Asaf and Brian [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271003/673223). I have my own questions on this:

1. **Asking for an alternative proof approach:** I am following Halmos's *Naïve Set Theory*, and he gives this as an exercise just after proving well ordering theorem, and *not* in the previous section dealing with Zorn's lemma. It's as if he intends to use well ordering theorem to prove this. And I am just scratching my head how well ordering might be used here to give a proof. Everywhere, Zorn's lemma seems to be used for this.
2. **Asking for a proof explanation:** [Brian's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271003/673223) to the above linked question uses Zorn's lemma on the set $\mathscr L$, partially ordered by inclusion, of all the total orders extending the given partial order on the original set, say $P$. But the answer invokes Zorn's lemma by showing that any chain $\mathscr C$ in $\mathscr L$ has an upper bound in $\mathscr L$. The answer mentions to take the obvious choice for this upper bound, which I assume is $\bigcup \mathscr C$. But then this doesn't seem to work if $\mathscr C = \emptyset$. What am I missing? Note that what is to be proven is that $\mathscr L$ *is* nonempty.

---

drhab (in comments) has resolved the second question: Brian in his answer, means the *restriction* of $\le$ to $X\times X$, when he writes $\le\upharpoonright(X\times X)$. Hence $\mathscr L$ is the set of all the total orders on subsets $X$ of $P$ such that they extend the restriction of $\le$ on $X\times X$.

Comment: If chain $\mathscr C=\varnothing$ then every element of $\mathscr{L}$ serves as an upper bound of the chain. So $\mathscr{L}\neq\varnothing$ is enough then.

Comment: But then, what we are proving is that $\mathscr L$ *is* nonempty.

Comment: Isn't it evident that $\mathscr L$ is not empty? You can take a singleton for $X$ equipped with equality relation. The aim is not to prove that $\mathscr L$ is not empty but that it has a maximal element.

Comment: @drhab But then, this does not contain the original order, does it? (Also, by $X$, you mean the given poset, right?)

Comment: The maximal element $M$ contains the original order $P$. This according to the third bullet in the answer of Brian. By $X$ I mean an element of $\mathscr L$ (defined in the answer of Brian). If $p$ is an element of $P$ then we can take $X=(\{p\},=)\in\mathscr L$.

Comment: @drhab But $\mathscr L$ is defined to contain only those $\langle X, \preceq_X\rangle$ such that $\preceq_X$ is an *extension* (and not just compatible on the common elements of $P$ and $X$) of the order $\le$ on $P$, in the sense that $\preceq_X\supseteq\le$ (viewing these as subsets of $P\times P$). And most likely $\{(p,p)\}\nsupseteq \le$. Where am I not getting it? (Thanks for your patience!)

Comment: (See for example how Asaf defines a set in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271009/673223).)

Comment: $X$ is a *subset* of $P$ equipped with a linear order $\preceq_X$. This order is *not* necessarily an extension of order $\le$ on $P$. It is an extension of $\le$ *restricted to* $X\times X$. If $X$ is a proper subset of $P$ then it is not even possible that we are dealing with an extension of $\le$ because in that case we do not have $\le\subseteq X\times X$. I am only talking about Brians answer here.

Comment: Again if $p\in P$ and $X=\{p\}$ equipped with linear order $\preceq_X=\{(p,p)\}$ then $\langle X,\preceq_X\rangle\in\mathscr L$. This because the restriction of $\le$ to $X\times X$ equals $\preceq_X=\{(p,p)\}$ (so formally is extended by $\preceq_X$).

Comment: @drhab I would have had a sleepless night if it were not for you!

Answer (score 3):

There's a recent proof by Michael Mandler, which I think is absolutely fantastic.

> *Mandler, Michael*, [**A quick proof of the order-extension principle**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2020.1801081), Am. Math. Mon. **127**, No. 9, 835 (2020). [ZBL07264146](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:07264146).

Fix a partial ordered set $(X,\leq)$.

1. $(X,\leq)$ embeds into $(\mathcal P(X),\subseteq)$ by $x\mapsto C_x=\{y\in X\mid x\leq y\}$.
2. Well order $X$, so without loss of generality, $X=\alpha$ for some ordinal.
3. $(\mathcal P(\alpha),\subseteq)$ has a natural linear order: $A\lhd B$ if and only if $A=B$ or $\min(A\mathbin{\triangle}B)\in B$. In other words, $A$ is smaller than $B$, if the first element not in both $A$ and $B$ lies in $B$.
4. Note that $\lhd$ extends $\subseteq$, since $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $A\mathbin{\triangle}B\subseteq B$.
5. Define $x\preceq y\iff C_x\lhd C_y$.
6. Note that if $x\leq y\iff C_x\subseteq C_y$ and therefore $x\leq y\to x\preceq y$, so $\preceq$ is a linear extension of $\leq$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading this as soon as I do some ordinals.